# Unable to trigger event on div with Jquery.

Tags: jquery, html

Essentially at this point I want to just display an alert when the clicking on MobileNavButton img class. I am unsure why but the "toggleme" class does not seem to be recognized when applied to an image but seems to work on the div which contains the UL.

HTML:

```
 <div id = "topNav">
   <div id = "navIcons">
   <img id="logo" class = "mobileLogo" src="images/navicons/logotext.png" alt="Devine Tofu Logo"/>

<!--This one does not trigger on click-->
   <img class = "toggleme mobileNavButton" src="images/navicons/logotext.png" alt="Devine Tofu Logo"/>
  </div>

<!-- this one does -->
   <div id = "flexcont" class = "toggleme">
   <ul id = "flexlist">
       <a href="#apparel">
           <li>Apparel</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#gal">
           <li>Gallery</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#contactmetitle">
           <li>Contact</li>
       </a>
       <a href="https://www.etsy.com/uk/shop/DivineTofu">
           <li>Etsy Store</li>
       </a>
   </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".toggleme").on("click", function() {

    alert("You Clicked Me");

});

});
```

Comment: Check for any event.stopPropagation();  and comment it to see what happens, event could be some other text like the letter e or anything. If you can paste more of your code in your post. I'm almost sure you have an event attached to the .mobileNavButton and when it is run it stops event propagation.

Comment: Hi TY for response, I have no other events taking place this is the first script on the site. The only other events as such are media queries and a few CSS transitions.

Comment: Do you have the site uploaded to a server so we can check it out?

Comment: No its all local atm, its 3am im going to try again tomorrow. I think I have done something wrong with my grid also so it might be worth me starting again. This site is just to learn on.

Comment: Alright Good luck.

Comment: Yes, strip out some stuff; should work.

Comment: I got it working eventually, its seems weird but is this jquery script only able to be triggerd against <a> tags? I can make it work if I wrap an <a> tag around an element and then assign the event trigger to that <a>  tag. Where as if I attempt to run this script an try and select an element ID it does not work.